# Animate tracks on an excavator by moving the excavator

Tags: animation, texture-coordinates

I like to animate tracks on an excavator by moving the excavator. I'm doing this to speed up animating process.

Moving the excavator forward or back will animate track accordingly. The track should look like it sticks to the ground and not sliding. Another fancy feature is when the object is turning, the tracks will rotate accordingly, but I want to figure out forward/backward motion first.

This is probably done using shader nodes. I just been using blender for 3 months, so I'm such a noob.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4FOUtCXogY&t=26s

Comment: You're talking about tracks that are really meshes or just some track texture? Because the shader nodes are used to setup materials and textures etc. So, presuming you have real track meshes, I would follow @mqbakamqbaka's example and find tutorials on youtube for tank tracks. This is not a simple question like "you want this, do that".

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!